# How to fix indicator icons from being cut off?

Tags: 10.04, indicator, gnome-panel

[image]

A friend of mine just upgraded from 9.10 to 10.04 and the icons for the indicator applets all appear cut off on both the bottom and the top. See picture above. Note that the icons in the old systray/notification area on my friend's panel all still display correctly, so it's a problem with indicator clearly. My question: How can this be fixed? (I have a 10.04 system that I did a fresh install on, and I don't have this issue, so I'm guessing it's an issue with upgrading. Thanks.

Comment: Try refreshing your gnome-panels `killall gnome-panel`

Comment: This happens every time my friend logs in, so I don't think that would work. Or is there a different reason that it might? (I can tell them to try it anyway.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one seems to have an answer to this, so I'm going to mark that the solution is to file a bug report, which I'll do later and leave in a comment here.

Answer (score 1):

If the refresh / re-login doesn't fix it, and you are willing to sacrifice a couple of pixels as a work-around you can right-click on gnome-panel and change Properties > Size.

Comment: Logged in a few times so far and it's exactly the same. Might use the panel pixel width as a workaround, but it's not a very pretty solution.

Comment: Nope, not pretty at all. You appear to be using a theme that I've not seen before and I have no idea how themes affect sizing, but upon looking at your image again, it occurs to me that it could be relevant.

Comment: It's clearlooks, which is one of the default installed themes. So I'd hope that's not the issue. But I guess it could be depending on from where it's pulling the icons for that theme. But don't they all just resize to fit the panel normally?